# How do I get a list of all the ASCII characters using Python?

Tags: python, ascii

I'm looking for something like the following:

```
import ascii

print(ascii.charlist())
```

Which would return something like `["A", "B", "C", "D" ... ]`.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

The constants in the [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-constants) may be what you want.

All ASCII capital letters:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

All [printable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable) ASCII characters:

```
>>> string.printable
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```

For every single character defined in the [ASCII standard](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf), use [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr):

```
>>> ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(128))
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f'
```

Comment: Interesting that `string.printable` limits itself to ASCII characters only.  And I'm not sure how many contexts would be able to properly interpret the vertical tab `\x0b`.

Comment: Beware that `string.printable` contains non-printable characters https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/67206

Answer (score 39):

Here it is:

```
[chr(i) for i in range(128)]
```

Comment: For those curious, `sorted({chr(i) for i in range(128)} - set(string.printable))` is `['\x00', '\x01', '\x02', '\x03', '\x04', '\x05', '\x06', '\x07', '\x08', '\x0e', '\x0f', '\x10', '\x11', '\x12', '\x13', '\x14', '\x15', '\x16', '\x17', '\x18', '\x19', '\x1a', '\x1b', '\x1c', '\x1d', '\x1e', '\x1f', '\x7f']`

Answer (score 21):

ASCII defines 128 characters whose byte values range from 0 to 127 inclusive.  So to get a string of all the ASCII characters, you could just do

```
''.join(chr(i) for i in range(128))
```

Only 100 of those are considered printable. The printable ASCII characters can be accessed via

```
import string
string.printable
```

Comment: Beware that `string.printable` contains non-printable characters https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/67206

Answer (score 6):

Since ASCII printable characters are a pretty small list (bytes with values between 32 and 126 inclusive), it's easy enough to generate when you need:

```
>>> for c in (chr(i) for i in range(32, 127)):
...     print(c)
... 
 
!
"
#
$
%
... # a few lines removed :)
y
z
{
|
}
~
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without a module:

```
characters = list(map(chr, range(97, 123)))
```

Type `characters` and it should print `["a","b","c", ... ,"x","y","z"]`. For uppercase use:

```
characters = list(map(chr, range(65, 91)))
```

Any range (including the use of range steps) can be used for this, because it makes use of Unicode. Therefore, increase the `range()` to add more characters to the list.

`map()` calls `chr()` every iteration of the `range()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(0, 128):
    print(chr(i))
```

Comment: ASCII would be `range(0, 128)`.

Comment: @dan04 @lucemia ASCII from 0 to **127**, extended codes are up to 255

Comment: @Andrey: ASCII is from 0 to 127, so range(0, 128) in Python. (A common error in several other answers...)

Comment: Python's range function subtracts 1 from the upper limit. range(128) represents the numbers 0 through 127

Answer (score -10):

No, there isn't, but you can easily make one:

```
    #Your ascii.py program:
    def charlist(begin, end):
        charlist = []
        for i in range(begin, end):
            charlist.append(chr(i))
        return ''.join(charlist)

    #Python shell:
    #import ascii
    #print(ascii.charlist(50, 100))
    #Comes out as:

    #23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abc
```

Comment: Three years after [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891469/321973) clearly mentions `string.printable`, you claim "no, there isn't"?