# python strip function not working properly

Tags: python, web-scraping, strip

I am scraping some data from a website via python.

I want to do two things

1. I want to skip the first 2 words "Dubai" and "UAE" which are common in every webscraping result.
2. I want to save the last two words in two different variables with strip without the extra spaces.

   ```
       try:
           area= soup.find('div', 'location')
           area_result= str(area.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8"))
           print "Area: ",area_result
   except StandardError as e:
           area_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
           print area_result
   ```

**area_result:** consists of the following data:

```
'UAE \xe2\x80\xaa>\xe2\x80\xaa\n            \n                Dubai \xe2\x80\xaa>\xe2\x80\xaa\n            \n                Business Bay \xe2\x80\xaa>\xe2\x80\xaa\n            \n                Executive Towers \n            \n\n\n        \n\n\n\t    \n\t        \n\t    \n\t\n\n\n        \n        ;\n        \n            \n                \n                    1.4 km from Burj Khalifa Tower'
```

I want the above result to be displayed as (Note the `>` between `Executive Towers` and `1.4 km..`

```
Executive Towers > 1.4 km from Burj Khalifa Tower
```

Comment: Could you possibly show us the string in it's original format instead of a screenshot? Like so: `UAE >\n              Dubai >\n       ...`? Also `strip()` is intended to strip things in the beginning and end of strings,

Comment: check the edited version

Comment: Your browser won't show you extraneous whitespace either.

Comment: @user3265370 You're still not giving us a **STRING**, you're giving us screenshots which we're not interested in.. Can you pleaes copy and paste the string **as is** instead of posting screenshots because i'm interested in why there's multiple `\n` and ` ` all over your data and how the raw data looks like, also i'd like to copy and paste that data into my environment so i can work with it. I can't copy a string from a screenshot. **Note:** That last screenshot doesn't match the first one, there's no `Dubai Festival City;` in the first screenshot even tho that doesn't matter much. consistency!

Comment: check the edited version please

Comment: @user3265370 No that's not the correct string.. Obviously that was taken from the browser and not your own code. Do this instead `print([area_result])`! (A logical mind would think that the browser is doing something to the string, and if the problem is with the code then i should copy the string from the code and not from the end where it's working?)

Comment: check the edited version again please

Comment: @user3265370 Please do `print([area_result])` and post **that** result...

Comment: I am already posting that. i am using sublime and posting the result of my console screen

Comment: I'm using sublime and this is what my output looks like `['Area:  UAE \u202a>\u202a\n\n                Dubai \u202a>\u202a\n\n                JLT Jumeirah Lake Towers \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n        ;\n\n\n\n                    1.4 km from Marina Walk']`, The **difference** is that i'm printing with `[]` around the string and i leave the data as is, and if your sublime works differently run the code from a PROPER terminal...

Comment: @user3265370 FINALLY!!!!

Comment: yes. i got it. i am sorry for the mistake. please check the edit

Comment: @user3265370 Check my edit on my answer, solves your problem (verified)

Comment: @user3265370 You're not running the latest version of my code.. because there's \t in there among other things.

Comment: done! solves it perfectly! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import string
def cleanup(s, remove=('\n', '\t')):
    newString = ''
    for c in s:
        # Remove special characters defined above.
        # Then we remove anything that is not printable (for instance \xe2)
        # Finally we remove duplicates within the string matching certain characters.
        if c in remove: continue
        elif not c in string.printable: continue
        elif len(newString) > 0 and c == newString[-1] and c in ('\n', ' ', ',', '.'): continue
        newString += c
    return newString
```

Throw something like that in there in order to cleanup your code?
The net result is:

```
>>> s = 'UAE \xe2\x80\xaa>\xe2\x80\xaa\n            \n                Dubai \xe2\x80\xaa>\xe2\x80\xaa\n            \n                Business Bay \xe2\x80\xaa>\xe2\x80\xaa\n            \n                Executive Towers \n            \n\n\n        \n\n\n\t    \n\t        \n\t    \n\t\n\n\n        \n        ;\n        \n            \n                \n                    1.4 km from Burj Khalifa Tower'
>>> cleanup(s)
'UAE > Dubai > Business Bay > Executive Towers 1.4 km from Burj Khalifa Tower'
```

Here's a good SO reference to the [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891453/is-there-a-python-library-that-contains-a-list-of-all-the-ascii-characters) library.

Going back to the question is see that the user don't want the first two blocks (between `>`) to be present, quite simply do:

```
area_result = cleanup(area_result).split('>')[3].replace(';', '>')
```

Comment: i want something which can be put in the line block of code which i already wrote

Comment: @user3265370 You put this at the top of your code, and all you have to do is: `print "Area: ",cleanup(area_result)`

Comment: done. but the result is still not well formatted. please check the result in the edited version

Comment: @user3265370 Please post what i'm asking you to post and not some own version of the data... Because it looks like you have unicode characters in there which needs to be delt with...

Comment: I am sorry but what exactly you want me to post?

Comment: Save your code, open up a terminal, run the code where you **keep** the `[  ]` around `area_result` so that we can get a string that looks like this: `['Area:  UAE \u202a>\u202a\n\n                Dubai \u202a>\u202a\n\n                JLT Jumeirah Lake Towers \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n        ;\n\n\n\n                    1.4 km from Marina Walk']`

Comment: @user3265370 also check my latest edit and see if that fixes it.

Comment: check the result please. the 3rd and forth word still have some spaces

Comment: @user3265370 You didn't run the latest version of the code, refresh this page and copy my code again. Because there's `\t` (which is a tab) and it shouldn't be there if you run the latest code.

Comment: @user3265370 You're welcome, next time post what we ask you to post.. Not some glorified version of it. The **truth** is always better than a made up story.. goes for data as well.

Comment: sorry for that. i missed the [ ]

Comment: one more request. can u add a delimiter between 3rd and 4rth word? so that later i can use excel to separate them easily

Comment: i want `>` between word 3 and word 4

Comment: @user3265370 You mean between `'Business Bay > Executive Towers 1.4 km from Burj Khalifa Tower'`? Or which do you refer to as `3` and `4` word? Write the string as you want it to look like, and i'll make it happen. So write the string in `sublime` as you want it to look like and i'll code it...

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I want a `>` between  Executive Towers  and 1.4 km from Burj Khalifa Tower'
it looks like Executive Towers `>` 1.4 km from Burj Khalifa Tower'

Comment: I have edited the question from you to make it more clear to understand

Comment: @user3265370 fixed it, it's quite simple, I just made it so that ';' doesn't get removed, that way you can use that as a "split" character. or do `cleanup(area_results).replace(';', '>')` or you can do the `replace` inside `cleanup`, up to you.

Comment: can i ask one more question please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728966/removing-the-unwanted-spaces-from-string-via-python?noredirect=1#comment34640004_22728966

Answer (score 2):

```
area_result = area_result.replace("UAE", "")
area_result = area_result.replace("Dubai", "")
area_result =  area_result.strip()
```

Using regular expression:

```
import re
area_result = re.sub('\s+',' ',area_result)
area_result = area_result.replace("UAE ‪>‪ Dubai ‪>‪", "")
area_result =  area_result.strip()
```